# Can I use a Wix domain for a NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, web-hosting, velo

This may be a silly question but I was wondering if I would be able to use my wix domain mfall33.com when deploying my node app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure how Wix is working, but if you paid for a domain name, you should be able to link your domain (mfall33.com) to an IP address.

So yes, you should be able to use your domain when you will deploy your node app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have been a bit confused.

A [Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) is the name of your website, i.e. the URL.
[Wix](https://www.wix.com/) is a system to build a website.
Node JS is a technology to build a server.

Today as [Wix Code](https://www.wix.com/code/home) released, I believe you can send events from Wix (client side) to your Node (server side).

You can change the DNS in order for your domain to point to your Node server in case you don't use the client side of Wix.